# Prevent link creation in global navigation when a new page is created Sharepoint 2013

Tags: navigation

How can I stop Sharepoint from creating a link in the Global Navigation Bar each time I create a new page for a subsite?

Answer (score 0):

I found out how! From Look and Feel -> Navigation -> Add new pages to navigation automatically. You must uncheck the box.